# Regex: How to select float value in JSON string

Tags: regex

How to select float number in JSON below.
I wish to select only value of `cummulativeQuoteQty`, so I wish to select `2221.98` value

```
{"orderId": 431708286, "clientOrderId": "eYKLCLsatTklXnphSd6ffF", "transactTime": 1676486706186, "price": "0", "origQty": "22.3", "executedQty": "22.3", "cummulativeQuoteQty": "2221.98", "status": "FILLED", "timeInForce": "GTC", "type": "MARKET", "side": "SELL", "fills": [{"price": "1.389", "qty": "22.3", "commission": "0.00007653", "commissionAsset": "BNB"}], "isIsolated": false}
```

Comment: Why do this with a regex? Use a JSON parser and select the specific element you want.

Comment: And since it's in quotes, it's a string, not a float.

Comment: @Barmar to be fair, json *is* a string, so all values are strings.

Comment: @Bohemian I'm clearly talking about the value represented in the JSON.

Comment: @Barmar of course, but values only become non-strings after interpretation by a parser. Without parsing, it and all its parts are just text. Semantics perhaps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you *must* use regex instead of a json parser:

```
(?<="cummulativeQuoteQty": ")[^"]+
```

See [live demo](https://rubular.com/r/hSLkCIUaZRNeH7).

Note that this approach is brittle to formatting, and it less readable than parsing json, which most software supports, and getting the field value by name.

Comment: I am testing selecting some logs from MySQL database using `REGEXP_SUBSTR`

Comment: @stan Since 5.7 MySQL has a built-in JSON datatype.